# Problems opening MapSurfer layers

Tags: openlayers-2, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, quickmapservices

Why won't Mapsurfer OSM layers open anymore from the QuickMapServices plugin in QGIS version 3

Answer (score 3):

1. Use OpenMapSurfer. MapSurfer seems to be dead.
2. Use QMS search. Embedded QMS catalog is going to be shut down soon.

Yours, QMS creators.

[image]